# Deletion of dict entries in for loop doesn't work, why?

Tags: python, xml, dictionary

I have this code that, starting from an input XML file,

- stores the index of child elements of a tag and the child elements as key, values in a dictionary;
- deletes keys whose values contain a certain string;
- joins the dict values and extracts their text;
- replaces certain strings with "";
- counts the occurrences of some specific regex I specify.

The code works fine, but it doesn't delete keys whose values contain the string "10.238". Below is the whole code:

```
import re
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


def filter_values_by_keyword(my_dict, filter_by):
    """
    Return a list of values which contains `filter_by` keyword.

    Arguments:
        my_dict (dict): Dict containing (...data specifics here)
        filter_by (str): Keyword to look for in values of my_dict

    Return:
        List of filtered values
    """
    return [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by in value]


def get_xml_by_tag_names(xml_path, tag_name_1, tag_name_2):
    """
    Your docstring here.
    """
    data = {}
    xml_tree = minidom.parse(xml_path)
    item_group_nodes = xml_tree.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_1)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(tag_name_2)
        for _ in cl_compile_nodes:
            data[idx]=[item_group_node.toxml()]
    return data


def main():
    data = get_xml_by_tag_names('output2.xml', 'new_line', 'text')
    filtered_values = filter_values_by_keyword(data, '10.238')

    for item in filtered_values:
        del data[item]

    mylist = []
    uncinata1 = " < "
    uncinata2 = " >"
    punto = "."
    virgola = ","
    puntoevirgola = ";"
    dash = "-"
    puntoesclamativo = "!"
    duepunti = ":"
    apostrofo = "’"
    puntointerrogativo = "?"
    angolate = "<>"

    for value in data.values():
        myxml = ' '.join(value)
        # print(myxml)

        tree = ET.fromstring(myxml)
        lista = ([text.text for text in tree.findall('text')])
        testo = (' '.join(lista))
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata1, "")
        testo = testo.replace(uncinata2, "")
        testo = testo.replace(punto, "")
        testo = testo.replace(virgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoevirgola, "")
        testo = testo.replace(dash, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntoesclamativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(duepunti, "")
        testo = testo.replace(apostrofo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(puntointerrogativo, "")
        testo = testo.replace(angolate, "")
        print(testo)

        find_prima = re.compile(r"\]\s*prima(?!\S)")
        find_fase_base = re.compile(r"\]\s*AN\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] AN parole da cui T
        find_fase_base_2 = re.compile(r"\]\s([\w\s]+)\s[→]\sT")  # ] parole → T
        find_fase_base_3 = re.compile(r"\]\s*([\w\s]+)\s*da\scui\sT")  # ] parole da cui T
        find_fase_12 = re.compile(r"\]\s1\s([\w\s]+)\s2\s([\w\s]+[^T])")  # ] 1 parole 2 parole (esclude T)
        find_fase_12_leo = re.compile(
            r"(?!.*da cui)\]\s+AN\s1\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)\s+2\s+([a-zA-Z]+(?:\s+[a-zA-Z]+)*)")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole escludendo da cui dopo
        find_fase_12T_leo = re.compile(
            r"\]\s*AN\s*1\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*2\s*([\w\s]+)da\s*cui\s*T")  # ] AN 1 parole da cui 2 parole parola da cui T
        matches_prima = re.findall(find_prima, testo)
        lunghezza_prima = len(matches_prima)
        mylist.append(lunghezza_prima)

    count = 0
    for elem in mylist:
        count += elem

    print(count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But the part that matters is:

```
def filter_values_by_keyword(my_dict, filter_by):

    return [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by in value]
```

and then in the main() function:

```
filtered_values = filter_values_by_keyword(data, '10.238')

for item in filtered_values:
    del data[item]
```

It returns the text as it is and I don't understand why.

EDIT:

This is a sample of my XML, it actually has `pages` tag repeating:

```
<pages>
  <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
    <textbox id="0" bbox="191.745,592.218,249.042,603.578">
<textline>
     <new_line>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="297.284,540.828,300.188,553.310" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">della quale non conosce che una parte;] </text>
              <text font="PYNIYO+ImprintMTnum-Italic" bbox="322.455,540.839,328.251,553.566" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.727">prima</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="331.206,545.345,334.683,552.834" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="7.489">1</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="177.602,528.028,180.850,540.510" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">che nonconosce ancora appieno;</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="189.430,532.545,192.908,540.034" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="7.489">2</text>
              <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum" bbox="203.879,528.028,208.975,540.510" colourspace="DeviceGray" ncolour="0" size="12.482">che</text>
            </new_line>
</textline>
</textbox>
</page>
</pages>
```

Comment: Why do you use both minidom and ElementTree? The question is tagged "lxml". Where is the input XML? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I deleted the unnecessary tag and provided a sample of the input XML in my question,let me know if it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you replace:

```
return [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by in value]
```

by:

```
return [key for key, value in my_dict.items() if filter_by == value]
```

or (*a more readable effort*) by:

**Update**

The input key is a of `str` type, and by your comment, the value is also an string type. Simply create an string `a="this is my 10.238 number"` the operation `"10.238" in a` gives a nice `True`.

I would double check the types in both the operators at the time you deal with the string having "10.238".

```
my_keys=[]

for key, value in my_dict.items()
  if isinstance(value, list):
    if filter_by in value:
       my_keys.append(key)
  elif isinstance(value, str):
    print("compare {} to {}".format(type(filter_by), type(value)))

    if filter_by in value or value.index(filter_by) > -1:
       my_keys.append(key)
  else:
    print("ops! {}".format(type(value)))


return my_keys
```

Comment: it is a substring so I have to use "in", thank you for the response. With the more readable effort, I get the same result- it doesn't delete anything :( maybe the functions aren't working well with each other?

Comment: mmm, probably the comparison is between float and string types. I'll update the post.

Comment: It makes sense, but it doesn't work...  it still doesn't delete those entries. "filtered values" is empty

Comment: how was it fixed? I'm curious